# Core data date and boolean attributes cannot be updated

Tags: ios, core-data

I am still learning how to program in iOS. In the project I am undertaking, I am trying to update the information in the core data but I hit a roadblock. I cannot update the date and Boolean attributes. Please help! The following is that part of the program that I am stucked. The output from the NSLog is followed.

```
ItemUpdateViewController *updateView = segue.sourceViewController;

NSDateFormatter* formattedDate = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
formattedDate.dateFormat = @"dd/MM/yyyy";


// Update lastDone1 date

[self.monitorItem setValue:
    [formattedDate dateFromString:updateView.lastDone1TextField.text]
                            forKey:@"lastDone1"];

NSLog(@"lastDone1 text: %@", updateView.lastDone1TextField.text);
NSLog(@"lastDone1 from updateView: %@", 
    [formattedDate dateFromString:updateView.lastDone1TextField.text]);
NSLog(@"lastDone1 in self.monitorItem: %@",[self.monitorItem valueForKey:@"lastDone1"]);


// Update fixed boolean value

[self.monitorItem setValue:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"fixed"];

NSLog(@"fixed: %@",[self.monitorItem valueForKey:@"fixed"]);
```

OutPut:
2014-05-02 17:17:48.334 SGRecencyMonitor[805:70b] lastDone1 text: 02/05/2014
2014-05-02 17:17:48.336 SGRecencyMonitor[805:70b] lastDone1 from updateView: 2014-05-01 16:00:00 +0000
2014-05-02 17:17:48.336 SGRecencyMonitor[805:70b] lastDone1 in self.monitorItem: (null)

2014-05-02 17:17:48.336 SGRecencyMonitor[805:70b] fixed: (null)

As shown, the core data returns both (null) values.

## Update:

Thanks nmh! I have added the following:

```
    SGRMAppDelegate *appDelegate = (SGRMAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate saveContext];
```

However the result is still the same. It both return (null) values.

Answer (score 0):

After you assign value to core data object, you save database

```
[self.monitorItem setValue:
[formattedDate dateFromString:updateView.lastDone1TextField.text]
                        forKey:@"lastDone1"];
// need to save database here:
[APP_DELEGATE saveContext];
```

Comment: Maybe self.monitorItem is nil! Please double check this variable

Comment: Thank you nmh. Yes the self.monitorItem is null. There is a fundamental in the design due to my lack of understanding. Managed to do a major re-design and it is ok now.